# [PHP][Imagick] Conserve image transparency while masking

Tags: php, image, image-processing, mask, imagick

I work on imagick (PHP) and I want to apply a mask on an image. Basically, it works fine. But it doesn't work as expected when it has to deal with transparency on the main image. Let me explain it.

**Source image (SD)**

[image: Source image]

**Mask Image (TPL)**

[image: Mask image]

**Result image :( (DEST)**

[image: Result image :(]

**Expected result**

[image: Expected result]

As you can see on the images the transparency of the source is not on the result...

So, here is my code :

```
$sd = 'tiger.png';
$tpl = 'tpl.png';
$dest = 'tiger_cut.png';

$base = new Imagick($sd);
$mask = new Imagick($tpl);

$base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$base->writeImage($dest);
```

I tried several options on compositeImage() but... couldn't find the right one(s).

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
$sd = 'tiger.png';
$tpl = 'tpl.png';
$dest = 'tiger_cut.png';

$base = new Imagick($sd);
$mask = new Imagick($tpl);

$base->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$base->writeImage($dest);
```